# Firebase : How to search all objects with same value in whole database or nested database

Tags: java, android, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database

How to get all objects with the same `name_mov` value from the nested database. I have a `EditText` from where I get a string for searching for objects with the same `mov_name` value from the nested database. I want to show the list of all objects under `bolly/new` and also `bolly/popular` with same `mov_name` value in `RecyclerView` with Firebase-UI.

Here is the database structure:

[image]

What have I done -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);


    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.spin_search);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rec_search);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    editText = findViewById(R.id.ed_search);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            firebaseSearch(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
}


//search data
private void firebaseSearch(String s) {
    /*Toast.makeText(AllUserActivity.this, "Started Search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    Query firebaseSearchQuery = mDatabaseReference.equalTo(s);

    //set Options
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MovieObj> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<MovieObj>()
                    .setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery, MovieObj.class)
                    .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                    .build();


    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MovieObj, SearchMovHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchMovHolder holder, int position, @NonNull MovieObj model) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            holder.name.setText(model.getName_mov());
            holder.rating.setText( model.getRating());
            holder.year.setText( model.getYear());

            Glide.with(holder.img_back.getContext())
                    .load(model.getImgback())
                    .into(holder.img_back);


        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public SearchMovHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_mov_item, parent, false);
            return new SearchMovHolder(mView);
        }


    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can achieve this using your database structure since between your root node and the objects that contain the `name_mov` property there are 4 childs, `mov`, `bolly`, `new` and the pushed id.

You can use the following query:

```
Query firebaseSearchQuery = mDatabaseReference
    .child("mov")
    .child("bolly")
    .child("new")
    .orderByChild("name_mov")
    .equalTo(s);
```

But you'll only be able to get the movie titles that exist within the `new` node. If you want to get all titles you should restructure your database by adding the type of the movie (new, popular and so on) as a property of your objects and then simply use:

```
Query firebaseSearchQuery = mDatabaseReference
    .child("mov")
    .child("bolly")
    .orderByChild("name_mov")
    .equalTo(s);
```

In this way, you'll a have level less and the query will work perfectly fine.

Comment: I can't change my database structure. Should I make multiple firebase queries and combine the response of those queries in a single list for showing in recyclerview? or there is any way to archive it.

Comment: Yes, you can also go ahead that way but only if you have 2 or 3 such nodes. If you have more than that, I still recommend you change your database structure.